# How to add headers in a bidi redirect?

Tags: redirect, clojure, header, cors, bidi

I have the following redirect:

```
#bidi.ring.Redirect{:status 307, :target "https://some-url"}
```

To which I'm trying to add cors headers like so:

```
(let [redirect (->Redirect 307 "https://some-url")
        redirect- (assoc redirect
                         :headers
                         {"Access-Control-Allow-Origin"
                          "https://some-url"
                          "Access-Control-Allow-Methods"
                          "POST, GET, OPTIONS"
                          "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" "Content-Type"
                          "Location" (:target redirect)
                          })
        ]
    (prn "redirect is " redirect-)
    redirect-)
```

I get the following print:

```
"redirect is" #bidi.ring.Redirect{:status 307, 
:target "http://some-url" 
:headers {"Access-Control-Allow-Origin" "https://some-url", 
"Access-Control-Allow-Methods" "POST, GET, OPTIONS", 
"Access-Control-Allow-Headers" "Content-Type"}}
```

Which seems correct. But when I make the request from the client, the response doesn't contain these headers. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you confirmed that the response the browser is receiving is actually the 307 response that you intend? Did you check the HTTP status code of the response? You can use the Network pane in browser devtools to check. You should confirm that what the browser is receiving isn’t actually some unexpected 4xx or 5xx error.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the `:headers` you put in Bidi's `Redirect` object don't go anywhere.

Indeed, if you follow the `bidi.ring.Redirect` reference to source code (https://github.com/juxt/bidi/blob/master/src/bidi/ring.cljc), you will see a hint that it will convert the Redirect to a Ring response of exactly,

```
 {:status  status
  :headers {"Location" location}
  :body    (str "Redirect to " location)}
```

I don't know much about Bidi, but perhaps you may simply return your own {:status 307, :headers {...}, :body "See elsewhere"} map if Bidi's Redirect is too restrictive.